# Grouping AND and OR conditionals in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, parentheses, operator-precedence

I always use brackets in sql queries. But I have example:

```
DELETE FROM prog 
WHERE prog_start >= $1 AND prog_start < $2
   OR prog_end > $1 AND prog_end <= $2
```

Is it equal to :

```
DELETE FROM prog
WHERE ( prog_start >= $1 AND prog_start < $2 )
   OR ( prog_end > $1 AND prog_end <= $2 )
```

or not ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In SQL the `AND` operator takes "precedence" over `OR` operator. PostgreSQL adheres to the spec here. You can the exact precedence in PostgreSQL in the docs [Lexical Structure: Operator Precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE).

So in your case, the result will be the same. However, it's much easier, and cleaner to simply use the parentheses.

Comment: There is an updated article for PostgreSQL 16 here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL

Answer (score 1):

It goes as per the Operator Precendence
 http://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.5/static/operators.htm#AEN1615.

To form a complex condition it's always better to parenthesis your conditions.

Comment: good analysis, but... wrong conclusion on this particular case, no ?

Comment: 6.5 is a bit outdated version to reference.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-OPERATORS
(or /and operators precedence changes are probably not the most usual changes, by the way...)

Comment: About referencing the PostgreSQL manual, consider http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual

Comment: Proper link to current manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-OPERATORS