# The parentheses rules of PostgreSQL, is there a summarized guide?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, semantics, any

In Mathematics and many programming languages (and I think *standard SQL* as well), parentheses [change precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331668/287948) (grouping parts to be evaluated first) or to enhance readability (for human eyes).
Equivalent Examples:

```
SELECT array[1,2] @> array[1]
SELECT (array[1,2]) @> array[1]

SELECT array[1,2] @> (array[1])
SELECT ((array[1,2]) @> (array[1]))
```

But  `SELECT 1 = ANY array[1,2]` is a syntax error (!), and `SELECT 1 = ANY (array[1,2])` is valid. Why?

OK, because ["the manual says so"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486). But what the logic for humans to remember all exceptions?
**Is there a guide about it?**

I do not understand why `(expression)` is the same as `expression` in some cases, but not in other cases.

---

PS1: parentheses are also used as value-list delimiters, as in `expression IN (value [, ...])`. But an array is not a value-list, and there does not seem to be a general rule in  PostgreSQL when `(array expression)` is not the same as `array expression`.
Also, I used array as example, but this problem/question is not only about arrays.

Comment: Since this is SQL, count yourself lucky that you don't have to write it as a mock-English phrase, like `SELECT 1 HAS ANY VALUE FROM ARRAY WITH VALUES 1 AND 2 AND 3 END` ;)

Answer (score 9):

*"Is there a summarized guide?"*, well... The answer is *no*, so: hands-on! This answer is a Wiki, let's write.

## Summarized guide

Let,

- *F*() a an usual function. (ex. `ROUND`)
- *L*() a function-like operator (ex. `ANY`)
- *f* a operator-like function (ex. `current_date`)
- *Op* an operator
- *Op1*, *Op2* are distinct operators
- A, B, C values or expressions
- S a expression-list, as "(A,B,C)"

The rules, using these elements, are in the form

- **rule**: notes.

### "pure" mathematical expressions

When *Op*, *Op1*, *Op2* are mathematical operators (ex. `+`, `-`. `*`), and *F*() is a mathematical function (ex. `ROUND()`).

Rules for **scalar expressions** and "**pure** array expressions":

- **A *Op* B = (A *Op* B)**: the parentheses is optional.
- **A *Op1* B *Op2* C**: need to check [precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331668/287948).
- **(A *Op1* B) *Op2* C**: enforce "first (A *Op1* B)".
- **A *Op1* (B *Op2* C)**: enforce "first (B *Op2* C)".
- ***F*(A) = (*F*(A)) = *F*((A)) = (*F*((A)))**: the parentheses are optional.
- **S = (S)**: the external parentheses are optional.
- ***f*=(*f*)**: the parentheses are optional.

### Expressions with function-like operators

Rules for operators as `ALL`, `ANY`, `ROW`, `SOME`, etc.

- ***L*(A) = *L*((A))**: the parentheses is optional in the argument.
- **(*L*(A))**: SYNTAX ERROR.

---

...More rules? Please help editing here.

Answer (score 3):

[**ANY**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18486) is a function-like construct. Like (almost) any other function in Postgres it *requires* parentheses around its parameters. Makes the syntax consistent and helps the parser avoid ambiguities.

You can think of `ANY()` like a shorthand for `unnest()` condensed to a single expression.

One might argue an additional set of parentheses around the [set-variant of `ANY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME). But that would be ambiguous, since a list of values in parentheses is interpreted as a single [`ROW` type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS).

Comment: In the right context, parens can also be a [row constructor](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS). So `SELECT (expression-list)...` is equivalent to `SELECT ROW(expression-list)...`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': Just thought of the same. :) Added the link you provided.

Comment: Yes, thanks! "function-like construct" make sense!   *ALL*, *ANY*, *ROW* and  *SOME* are in the real life `ALL()`, `ANY()`, `ROW()` and `SOME()`  as usual functions syntax... I must to register here  my "personal indignation" with [the PostgreSQL guide](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html) (!): no mention to "function" or "function-like", only *"... right-hand side is a parenthesized expression ... left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element"*, and no objective explanation.

Comment: Not to add to your indignation, but there is even a handful of functions *without* parentheses (adhering to the SQL standard and for historical reasons). Like [`current_date` or `current_timestamp`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)