# Ecto fragment without parentheses

Tags: postgresql, ecto, jsonb

My Postgres table structure:

```
   id   | stuff                                                                                                                                                                                                        
--------+------------------------------------------------------------
  123   | {"type1": {"ref": "ref_1", "...": "..."}, "type2": {"ref": "ref_1", "...": "..."}}
```

I'd like to query by `ref` in each type of stuff, I have a working SQL query for this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "stuff" AS c0 CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(c0."stuff") AS f1 WHERE value->>'ref' = 'ref_1';
```

But using this Ecto query:

```
(from c in Stuff,
  join: fragment("jsonb_each(?)", c.stuff),
  where: fragment("value->>'ref' = ?", ^ref)
)
|> Repo.all
```

I get a Postgres syntax error in the CROSS JOIN statement:

```
** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42601 (syntax_error): syntax error at or near ")"
```

Inspecting the generated query:

```
[debug] QUERY ERROR source="stuff" db=0.3ms
SELECT ... FROM "stuff" AS c0 CROSS JOIN (jsonb_each(c0."stuff")) AS f1 WHERE (value->>'ref' = $1) ["ref_1"]
```

The above works when I remove the outer parentheses around `(jsonb_each(c0."stuff"))`.

Is there a way to have the fragment generate the query without these parentheses or do I have to redesign the query?

Thanks

Comment: One of the obvious ways to bypass this is to use raw sql, an example can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27751216/how-to-use-raw-sql-with-ecto-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in ecto, has been fixed here https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2537

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Ecto always wraps the join clause in parentheses, which is usually fine. The times when its not unfortunately includes certain calls like the jsonb_each above. There is a wiki here for such cases: [The parentheses rules of PostgreSQL, is there a summarized guide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763940/the-parentheses-rules-of-postgresql-is-there-a-summarized-guide)

The linked raw sql example had a much less upvoted answer that seems to work well with both making this query and getting back the expected struct.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM "stuff" AS c0 CROSS JOIN jsonb_each(c0."stuff") AS f1 WHERE value->>'ref' = 'ref_1';"
result = JsonbTest.Repo.query!(sql)
Enum.map(result.rows, &JsonbTest.Repo.load(StuffStruct, {result.columns, &1}))
```

Comment: That's the approach I've taken, however, I really hope for a more Ecto way of solving this.